# Linear transformation (producing matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V and W be vector spaces. Fix a basis $\{v_i\}_i=1$ to $m$ of $V$ and a basis of $\{w_i\}_I=1$ to $n$ of $W$ . Then the map $L(V,W)\rightarrow M _{n,m} (\mathbb{R})$ given by $T \mapsto M(T)$ is a bijective. I don't know how to start and solve it . If someone could please help me?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider the linear map $C:V\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m,$ and $D:W\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ given by $C(v_i)=e_i$ and $D(w_i)=e_i$ for the basis an extending them linearly. If i give you a matrix $M\in M_{n,m}(\mathbb{R}).$ What if you consider the map:

$T_M:V\longrightarrow W,$ given by $T_M(v)=D^{-1}(M\cdot C(v)).$ 
 Are they inverses of each other?

Comment: You are completely right. I oversimplified.